# Mongodb insert bulk but filter existing record

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to do bulk insert, and leave existing records alone?

I have a model like this

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date
    }
});
```

Which ensure name is unqiue, then i use insert like below. My req.body.users is an array of object

```
[{name: 'akon'},{name:'bill'}]
```

It work if `akon` or `bill` is not present but failed if either of one existed in the document.

```
const Users = require('../models/users');
Users.collection.insert(req.body.users)
    .then((result) => {
      res.json({result})
})
.catch((err) => {
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, msg: `Something went wrong. ${err}` });
})
```

What I want is just insert whatever which is not present in the document, tried `insertMany`, it also doesn't have that option to do this simple operation. Not sure I should do loop and use findOneAndUpdate.

Comment: You already asked the question. You "avoid duplicates" by following what was explained to you in the answer given.

Comment: @NeilLunn you didn't give me a solution at all.

Comment: Certainly did. I suggest you go and read and run the example code and understand it.